# how to convert to c# code in php pack('s') method

Tags: c#, php, pack

I want to connect to a game server.
Blocked in the header portion.
help me t.t
ex) php code

```
$obj = new stdClass;
$obj->variable1     = 202;
$obj->variable2     = 123;
$str = json_encode($obj);
$header = "\x0a\xFF\x00\x10".pack("s",strlen($str)).$str;

.....

fwrite($sock, $header);
```

how to convert to c# code `pack("s",strlen($str))` and `$str` that json-type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can use json.net to do the json encoding, then something like the following:

```
var obj     = new StandardClass { variable1 = 202, variable2 = 123 };
var initial = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
var header  = "\x0a\xff\x00\x10" + initial.Length.ToString("X") + initial;
...
socket.Write(header);
```

Comment: new StandardClass { variable1 = 202, variable2 = 123 };    
new { variable1 = 202, variable2 = 123 };
equal?

Comment: new StandardClass creates a new instance of StandardClass and sets the properties using the object initialization format. The second one actually creates an anonymous type with the same variable names. They should encode to the same json, but the two are not equal.